# How to disable and uncheck checkboxes on check of checkbox?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a jquery script that disables all checkboxes in a row and marks them as checked:

```
$(function() {
  enable_cb();
  $("#group1").click(enable_cb);
});

function enable_cb() {
  if (this.checked) {
     $("input.group1").attr("disabled", true);
     $("input.group1").attr("checked", true);
  } else {
     $("input.group1").removeAttr("disabled","checked");

  }
}
```

Here is my fiddle with the html: http://jsfiddle.net/3fksv/16/

I want the rest of the checkboxes to show active again, and unchecked on uncheck of the checkbox.  What am I doing wrong in my script?

Comment: Try using `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Comment: your call to enable_cb() on document.ready will make this.checked be undefined.  This is why it isn't initializing appropriately.  with attr you need to use 'checked'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that you can remove two attributes at once like that. You might have to use two calls to the `removeAttr()` function -

```
$("input.group1").removeAttr("disabled");
$("input.group1").removeAttr("checked");
```

As [@nickf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9021/nickf) correctly mentioned, these commands can also be chained -

```
$("input.group1").removeAttr("disabled").removeAttr("checked");
```

Comment: You can, but they have to be a single space-separated string

Comment: It's in the docs...  "An attribute to remove; as of version 1.7, it can be a space-separated list of attributes."

Comment: Either way though, with newer versions it's more correct to use .prop instead of .attr for checkbox state / disabled status.

Comment: wow - totally skimmed over that part :P good to know @sam! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`checked` and `disabled` are properties, as of jQuery 1.6 for modifying properties of the elements, `prop` method should be used instead of `attr`.

```
function enable_cb() {
   $("input.group1")
         .prop("disabled", this.checked)
         .prop("checked", this.checked);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JeqE5/

Comment: [documentation about removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) only talks about `.prop()` for problems with IE6/7/8, doesn't seem very clear to me :( Thanks for your answer

Comment: This works great in the fiddle, but doesn't work on my page :(

Comment: @Christo Do you see any error on the console? Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3fksv/18/

```
function enable_cb() {
   if (this.checked) {
      $("input.group1").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
      $("input.group1").attr("checked", 'checked');
   } else {
      $("input.group1").removeAttr("disabled","checked");
   }
}

$(function() {
   $("input.group1").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
   $("input.group1").attr("checked", 'checked');
   $("#group1").click(enable_cb);
});
```